# Validation of multiple empty field

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate two fields in my form.
But it is displaying the error message only for one field.
Following is Javascript code:

```
function req() {

    if (document.reg_indi_form.txt_fnm.value=="") {

        document.getElementById('i').innerHTML="*This field is required";
        document.getElementById('i').style.color="red";
        return false;
    }
     if (document.reg_indi_form.txt_lnm.value=="") {

        document.getElementById('i1').innerHTML="*This field is required";
        document.getElementById('i1').style.color="red";
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input name="txt_fnm" type="text" id="txt_fnm"/> <label id="i"></label>
<input name="txt_lnm" type="text" id="txt_lnm"/>\<label id="i1"></label>
```

Comment: put your `return` statement at the end instead of after each `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all errors tested, as "Disha" commented, you can not put a return statement in each if blocks.

```
var noError = true;

if (document.reg_indi_form.txt_fnm.value=="") {

    document.getElementById('i').innerHTML="*This field is required";
    document.getElementById('i').style.color="red";
    noError = false;
}
if (document.reg_indi_form.txt_lnm.value=="") {

    document.getElementById('i1').innerHTML="*This field is required";
    document.getElementById('i1').style.color="red";
    noError = false;
}

return noError;
```

That should work as you seems to want to.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

- JavaScript

  `

function validate(){

```
    var isValid = true;
    if (document.reg_indi_form.txt_fnm.value=="") {

    document.getElementById('i').innerHTML="*This field is required";
    document.getElementById('i').style.color="red";
    isValid = false;
}
 if (document.reg_indi_form.txt_lnm.value=="") {

    document.getElementById('i1').innerHTML="*This field is required";
    document.getElementById('i1').style.color="red";
    isValid = false;
}
return isValid;
}`
```